# Method to check if input is a string

Tags: php

I'm writing a method to check if an input is a string. I have this so far:

```
public function stringCheck($string){

    if (!empty($string) && is_string($string)){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, it will always return true because is_string accepts integers as well. Is there an alternative to is_string? I just want to make sure the input is not empty and is in fact a string (checking the length would be cool as well).

Cheers

Comment: [Its working fine](https://eval.in/396088)

Comment: Do you mean with *accepts integers* that it also accepts "24", which is a string?!

Comment: `if (!empty($string) && is_string($string) && !is_numeric($string)){`? If you don't want to allow strings containing a numeric value

Comment: Say the user inputs their firstname, it should only contain letters and not any numbers

Comment: You wanna check if it is alpha numeric?

Comment: @bri So you want to check if the input only cotains `a-zA-Z` ?

Comment: Can you post examples which this function won't allow to work @bri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function stringCheck($string){

    if (!empty($string) && ctype_alpha($string))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

It seems you want only alphabetic characters. So learn [ctype_alpha();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

Answer (score 0):

is_string() does not accept integers, unless you mean that '55' is an integer. 
But then you have to verify if the string contains any alphabetic characters.

Have a look at the doc:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP function is_string() will work fine to check whether the value is string or not. Please check whether you give the integer value without quotes

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, the `is_string` does not accept integers as well.

```
$num = 1;
$isString = is_string($num);
var_dump($isString);//false
```

Your problem is that you are passing a string, which contains an integer. If you do not want the string to conatin any integer or number you could use a regex.

```
$string = 'foo';
$isString = preg_match('/^([^0-9]*)$/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($isString); //true

$string = '44';
$isString = preg_match('/^([^0-9]*)$/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($isString); //false

//note that a combination retruns false too
$string = '44 foo';
$isString = preg_match('/^([^0-9]*)$/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($isString); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this also if it is exactly what you looking for:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php